# Removing leading letters and zeros from a string that can't be turned into a number

Tags: xml, xpath, trim, word-addins

I'm working in a word add in that uses xpath expressions to populate labels with information from an ERP system.

We have order numbers that come from the ERP that begin with one letter and then either 1-4 zeros.  Examples include:

```
o013148180-00
t005238905-01
```

How can I remove the leading letter and then any zero until you hit the first number greater than zero?
Results would be as follows:

```
13148180-00
5238905-01
```

substring by itself won't work because there will always be different amounts of leading zeros.  I have removed the letter by the following expression:

```bash
substring((PropertyLabel[@FieldName ='xxordhdr.order_number_and_suffix']/FieldValue),2)
```

And now cannot figure out the correct expression(s) to trim any leading zeros.  I have tried changing the simple function into a number to help remove any leading zeros and it does not allow it.

I have been able to cut the leading letter off.  I have tried different string functions to know avail and tried converting the data to a number but that is not working either as I get an error stating the function number is not recognized.

I have been looking through answers but I have found none that deal with multiple zeros of unknown quantity each time.  I'm not the most programming language savvy person so I apologize for any horribly written statements.

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with XPath 2.0?

```bash
for $fieldValue in
    //PropertyLabel[@FieldName="xxordhdr.order_number_and_suffix"]/FieldValue
return
    replace($fieldValue,"^[^1-9]+","")
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get somewhat there. 'replace' did not work as the word add in did not recognize it. However, I changed it to translate and it went through. So my Value XPath box looks like this now: translate(substring((PropertyLabel[@FieldName ='xxordhdr.order_number_and_suffix']/FieldValue),2),"^[^1-9]+","").  That produced an order number from the first example with all 1st removed - 03488000.